# Glimpse - Show Area as well as Action and Controller on execution tab

Tags: glimpse

Is there a way to show the Mvc area as well as the controller and action on the execution tab?

Answer (score 0):

Glimpse does not have this functionality.

It'd make a great pull request though if you are interested in contributing!

Comment: OK I'll have a look as I would find this very useful as without the area I am losing site of what is going on.

Comment: If you do decide to give it a go, let us know on the issues list and we can give you pointers, etc.